# For loop and if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop

I am working with the following for loop:

```
for (int intPrjName = 0; intPrjName < [arrPrjName count]; intPrjName++)
```

I have a if/else statement under the for loop, in which the `else` block shows an alert message. Suppose array count is 10; then when the `if` fails, the `else` block will execute ten times, and  the alert message displays ten times. How can I deactivate this?

Comment: Move the code that shows the alert out of the loop.

Comment: break from inside the else statement

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a general programing problem.  The simplest way is to just use a BOOL flag.

```
BOOL alertShown = NO;
for (int intPrjName = 0; intPrjName < [arrPrjName count]; intPrjName++) {
    if (something) {
        // . . .
    } else {
        if (!alertShown) {
            [self showAlert:intPrjName]; // Or something
            alertShown = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `what  showAlert method contains. please elaborate(iam not getting where the parameter intPrjName is used in that method)

Comment: Sorry, showAlert: is just an example. Check out Ziggy's answer for how to make a UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only one alert in case of failed condition that would probably mean you don't want to continue the loop. So as Jason Coco mentioned in his comment, you `break` from the loop. Here's a simple example on how to do this:

```
for (int intPrjName = 0; intPrjName < [arrPrjName count]; intPrjName++) {
   if (condition) {
      // do something
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to check some condition for every element of the array, you would probably want to keep track of failures and show user the summary (could be an alert message, another view, etc). Short example:

```
NSUInteger numFailures = 0;

for (int intPrjName = 0; intPrjName < [arrPrjName count]; intPrjName++) {
   if (condition) {
      // do something
   } else {
      numFailures++;
   }
}

UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                  message:@"Operation failed: %d", numFailures
                  delegate:nil
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                  otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
[alert show];
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assume C is  an Array where n is an int or NSNumber type caste to int

for(n in C){

if{n equal to 10)

dostuff
  }

else{
doOtherStuff
}
}

}

The good thing about this approach you can inore the size of the Array.

Look at the docs for Enumeration Glass