# looping in iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For loop and if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605458/for-loop-and-if-statement)

Hi everyone,
i have a following for loop and preeceding to it  a if else condition.m using the following code.

```
for (int intPrjName=0 ; intPrjName<[arrPrjName count]  ;intPrjName++)
{
    if ([strSelectedProjectName caseInsensitiveCompare:[arrPrjName objectAtIndex:intPrjName])
    { 
        //some code
    }
    else
    {
        //some code
    }

}
```

suppose strSelectedProjectName is "aaa"and the arrPrjName contains "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" .. after the first iteration of for loop if condition gets true i.e string "aaa" matches with the string in array list,it should get out of the loop at the second iteration,i.e it should not enter the else condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a break; command

```
for (int intPrjName=0 ; intPrjName<[arrPrjName count]  ;intPrjName++)
{
    if ([strSelectedProjectName caseInsensitiveCompare:[arrPrjName objectAtIndex:intPrjName])
    { 
        //some code
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //some code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` to exit the iteration loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **break** keyword:

```
for (...) {
  if (condition) {
    // do stuff
    break;
  } else {
    // do other stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `break;` in your loop to *break* out of the code if you do not want it to continue to loop.

```
for (int intPrjName=0 ; intPrjName<[arrPrjName count]  ;intPrjName++)
{
    if ([strSelectedProjectName caseInsensitiveCompare:[arrPrjName objectAtIndex:intPrjName])
    { 
        //some code
        break;//Get out of for loop
    }
    else
    {
        //some code
    }

}
```